# Stretch a background image (SVG) to 100% width and 100% height?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image, stretch

The behaviour I want to achieve is the width of `background-size:cover;`, but the height of `background-size:contain;` by stretching the image. I thought that `background-size:100%;` should do this, but look at the example - it does not.

```css
.container {
   background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg");
   background-position:center center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   width:300px;
   height:180px;
   background-color:#eef;
   border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

#container1 {
  background-size:contain;
}

#container2 {
  background-size:cover;
}
#container3 {
  background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="container"></div>

<div id="container2" class="container"></div>

<div id="container3" class="container"></div>
```

How can I achieve the desired - stretched - result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `background-size: 100%;` actually means `background-size: 100% auto;`. Use both width and height values: `background-size: 100% 100%;`

> Using a width value only, in which case the height defaults to auto.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Syntax

```css
.container {
   background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg");
   background-position:center center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   width:300px;
   height:180px;
   background-color:#eef;
   border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

#container1 {
  background-size:contain;
}

#container2 {
  background-size:cover;
}
#container3 {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="container"></div>

<div id="container2" class="container"></div>

<div id="container3" class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer is correct, BUT, somewhat incomplete: here's why...

If you want a background SVG image to stretch and fill the full container it's important to note the SVG must allow this to happen. In the SVG make sure you have ' preserveAspectRatio="none" ' added next to the viewport.

So use:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

And in the SVG make sure it looks something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

Comment: Phew, I thought I was getting mad, because intentionally stretching an SVG as a background image just didn't want to happen—until I realised it must have something to do with the SVG itself. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="none"` is what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

```css
.container {
   background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg");
   background-position:center center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   width:300px;
   height:180px;
   background-color:#eef;
   border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

#container1 {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="container"></div>
```