# Why does background-size:100% 100%; not work on this SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image, stretch

Look at the example:

```css
.container {
   background-image:url("http://svgshare.com/i/3cM.svg");
   background-position:center center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   width:400px;
   height:200px;
   background-color:#eef;
   border-bottom:1px solid #000;
   background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="container"></div>
```

Related question: [Stretch a background image (SVG) to 100% width and 100% height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978834/stretch-a-background-image-svg-to-100-width-and-100-height)

Comment: I believe you have to nest another elem within the container using 100%

Comment: Hmm in my live example this does not work either. There must be a problem with certain SVG files?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JknDr/123/ - this is working for a me on Chrome. if height is the issue, yeah you may need to find an svg that scales more proportionally.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open your .svg file and set

> `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

within the SVG tag.

Comment: Found related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334095/background-size100-100-doesnt-work-properly-in-chrome

Comment: this was driving me crazy. thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, wrap the svg container inside another one and give the wrapper the dimensions you need. In this case, I set the wrapper to `100vw` width and `100vh` height. Change the wrapper dimensions and notice that the svg will follow.

```css
html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.container {
   background-image:url("http://svgshare.com/i/3cM.svg");
   background-position:center center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background-color:#eef;
   border-bottom:1px solid #000;
   background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container1" class="container"></div>
</div>
```